# Como identificar valores duplicados en gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Estoy cargando un GridView con varios registros desde el formulario, un campo es E-mail, al final del proceso envío un correo a las direcciones agregadas en esa columna.
El problema es que normalmente se va a repetir el campo E-mail por tanto se envía el correo tantas veces se repita en el GridView al mismo destinatario.

Estoy tratando de evitarlo de esta manera pero no funciona:

```
 For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Text = row.Cells(0).Text Then
            'Duplicado
        Else
            'Enviar Correo
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: como estas enviando el correo, todos a la vez? yo lo que haria es supongamos que tiene 10 filas tu datagrid y hay 5 correos repetidos en tu columna, seleccionas una fila y en base al correo seleccionado recorres la columna buscando los demas repetidos y que se coloren de verde  y despues desde un boton enviar un solo correo y no 5 y una vez enviado se remuevan del datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos formas:

**Usando una lista**

Recorres los registros de tu GridView agregando cada correo a una lista nueva. Una vez que tu lista está llena la ordenas en orden alfabético (eso lo puedes hacer con el método [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)).

Así los registros duplicados aparecen de forma contigua y será fácil identificarlos. Para enviar los correos recorres la lista verificando que el elemento actual sea diferente del inmediato anterior, de lo contrario significa que está duplicado.

**Usando [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)**

HashSet es una estructura diseñada especialmente para manejar colecciones de objetos sin repeticiones.

Creas una instancia de HashSet. Recorres los registros de tu GridView y los agregas al HashSet. Al finalizar el HashSet contendrá todos los correos solo una vez. Bastará con recorrer sus elementos para enviar los correos.

Comment: esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta a la pregunta principal.

Answer (score 0):

Es que en tu lógica estas comparando si un registro es igual a uno mismo, es como hacer un 1 = 1, te va a dar siempre true.

Pensalo más simple, recorre con el **foreach** tus mails y carga en un **List** de string los correos a los que enviaste. Despues es simplemente validar antes de enviar el correo si ya fue enviado a esa dirección.

```
 Dim listCorreosEnviados As New List(Of String)
 Dim enviarCorreo As Boolean

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        enviarCorreo = True
        //Si ya envie correos, verifico en el listado que no este repetido.
        If listCorreosEnviados.Count > 0 Then
            For Each correo As String In listCorreosEnviados
                If row.Cells(0).Text = correo Then
                    enviarCorreo = False
                End If
            Next

            If enviarCorreo = True Then
                //Envio el correo
            End If

        Else
          //Envio el correo
        End If

        //Por cada mail enviado, agrego el correo al listado
        listCorreosEnviados.Add(row.Cells(0).Text)
    Next
```

Saludos.